# JavaScript file order when using hierarchy

Tags: javascript, class-hierarchy, load-order

I model a simple Hierarchy where class `B` extends class `A`. I use different `.js` files for `A` and `B`. My code contains the following line in `B.js`:

`B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);`

As this line is in the outermost/global scope (so not inside any other function, event handler, ...), I need to load `A.js` before.

However, I also have situations where I need to rename classes and/or automatically load `*.js` in a directory (for example when running karma). Taking care of the order of files is problematic in these cases.

How can I work around the issue of manually taking care that the class names match the order, or that the order is correct w.r.t. the file names?

Comment: Use a dependency manager?

Comment: For example, RequireJS.

Comment: wrt is one of those acronyms that needs to die in a fiery hell.

Comment: I fail to understand how I can provide class definitions using RequireJS. Could you show an example where the class hierarchy above (with `A` and `B`) is defined using RequireJS?

Comment: Got it. Just had a typo.